# Different login errors for custom CakePHP authentication

Tags: cakephp, authentication

I'm doing a site that requires double authentication, one from LDAP and one from local database. I did a custom authentication extending BaseAuthenticate and implementing custom `authenticate()` method, but as documentation says:

> Authentication objects should return false if they cannot identify the user. And an array of user information if they can.

I need to show an "invalid credentials" error when the user doesn't pass the LDAP authentication, and "access error, please contact the administrator" error when he isn't on the database, but I can't find a way to provide two different errors, as failed login just have to return false.

So, is there a way to show different messages?

Comment: I think you can store in session the kind of authentication problem you get and retrieve it in your controller

Comment: Not the most clean way, but it worked. Thanks